# ng-click not firing any event

Tags: php, html, angularjs

here it is my html part from where i m trying to enter details ..

```
<div  ng-app="angularPHP">
<div ng-controller="mainpagecntl">
     <div id="customer" class="cuscontainer" hidden="hidden">
        <div>
            <h3 class="modal-title" >Add customer</h3>
            <i class="fa fa-times" id="clo" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
            <table>
            <tr>

                <div class="form-group" >
                <td><label id="label"  class="control-label">customer Name:</label>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="customer_name"  />
                </div>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <td><label id="label" class="control-label">Address:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="customer_add"/></td>
            </div>
            </tr>
            </table>
                <div class="madal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"   ng-click="custadd()">ADD</button><br />

                </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

here is my angular-js part..

```
var app = angular.module('angularPHP', []);
     app.controller('mainpagecntl', function($http,$scope)
    {
        $scope.custadd= function()
          {
             data={
                     cname :$scope.customer_name,                            
                      cadd: $scope.customer_add,
                   }
                   $http.post("../pos_system/Widgets/addcust.php?add",data).success(function(data)
                   { 
                   });
                  }
        });
```

but when i click on button nothing happened my ng-click function is not firing.

Comment: Have you bootstrapped angular with the ng-app directive? Are you using the ng-controller directive?

Comment: i m using ng-controller directive.@DanielBornstrand

Comment: specify var for data object. Give console.log or alert in click function and check. comment remaining code

Comment: Can you show your controller?

Comment: have you firebuged it?It may be showing you some error

Answer (score 0):

> try adding `ng-controller="myCtrl"`at the `<div id="customer" class="cuscontainer" hidden="hidden">` like this

```
<div id="customer" class="cuscontainer" hidden="hidden" ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the function is not firing at all? It may be firing but just failing to post the data. console.log something straight away inside the function to check e.g.

```
var app = angular.module('angularPHP', []);

app.controller('mainpagecntl', function($http,$scope) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.custadd = function() {

      console.log('test');

      var data = { cname :$scope.customer_name, cadd: $scope.customer_add};

      $http.post("../pos_system/Widgets/addcust.php?add",data)
       .success(function(data) { 
        console.log(data);
       });

    }

}
```

Then your ng-click should look like this

```
ng-click='vm.custadd()'
```

See if that makes any difference.

Note: Your ng-controller should also look like

```
ng-controller="mainpagecntl as vm"
```

as noted in the comments below.

Comment: I think bharathv is right in the comment above that you may have forgotten to declare var for your data object.

Comment: Post your controller!

Comment: Have a look at my edit and see if that helps at all.

Comment: That's only if you do `ng-controller="mainpagecntl as vm"` - related to `ng-click='vm.custadd()'`

Comment: i m also testing in firebug no error showing and nothing is happening.@user2085143

Comment: Try adding the controller to the same div you have the ng-app on?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working demo https://plnkr.co/edit/k7yApAavre66KFAiVlOp?p=preview for your code and it worked perfectly when I clicked on Add button. Although I have removed some div tags from table as it's bad practice and Angular will not identify those tags when its directives are used on them.

```
var app = angular.module('angularPHP', []);
app.controller('mainpagecntl', function($http, $scope) {
    $scope.custadd = function() {
        $scope.data = {
            cname: $scope.customer_name,
            cadd: $scope.customer_add,
        }
       // $http.post("../pos_system/Widgets/addcust.php?add", data).success(function(data) {});
    }
});
```